# jquery after parent, find element

Tags: jquery, find, parent

I'm trying to access the parent of `$('.delete_button').click()` event to find a `p` tag and replace its contents, but with I can't seem to see where I'm doing it wrong in this code:

jquery:

```
//inside $('.delete_button').click() evvent
$(this).parent('.news_container').find('p').html(no_featured_news).removeClass('existing').addClass('description');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="news_container">
   <p class="existing">Lorem Lipsum</p>
   <button class="delete_button" data-id="1605361"></button>
</div>
```

Any ideas why the jquery code above doesn't finds the `p` tag? What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

jQuery click event:

```
$('.delete_news_order').click(function(){

  var image = $(this);
  if (id===undefined)
    id = $(this).data('id');

  console.log($(this).data('id'));

  $.post('do.php', { OP: "delete_order", id: id }, function(result){

      $(this).siblings('p').html(no_featured_news).removeClass('existing').addClass('description');
      ...
```

Comment: You usually want [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) not [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), but that ought to still work

Comment: @Rup, thanks for your advice... I will try `closest` see if works with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work fine. But you can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead:

```
$('.delete_button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p')
        .html("Text")
        .removeClass('existing')
        .addClass('description');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but still doesn't do it... check my updated question please

Comment: @w0rldart In the Ajax call `this` addresses not to your button anymore. Use 'cached' variable (e.g. `image`), so: `image.siblings('p')...`.